# How to generate a JSON log from nginx?

Tags: json, logging, nginx

I'm trying to generate a JSON log from nginx.

I'm aware of solutions like [this one](http://blog.pkhamre.com/2012/08/23/logging-to-logstash-json-format-in-nginx) but some of the fields I want to log include user generated input (like HTTP headers) which need to be escaped properly.

I'm aware of the nginx changelog entries from Oct 2011 and May 2008 that say:

```
*) Change: now the 0x7F-0x1F characters are escaped as \xXX in an
   access_log.
*) Change: now the 0x00-0x1F, '"' and '\' characters are escaped as \xXX
   in an access_log.
```

but this still doesn't help since `\xXX` is [invalid in a JSON string](http://json.org/).

I've also looked at [the HttpSetMiscModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSetMiscModule) module which has a `set_quote_json_str` directive, but this just seems to add `\x22` around the strings which doesn't help.

Any idea for other solutions to log in JSON format from nginx?

Comment: The link in your post gave me HTTP/500 ... since it's not core feature of nginx, I assume you are building from source by your own with a 3rd party modules. If that's the case you can simply edit the code and change \xXX to \uNNNN, like these lines: https://github.com/kayrus/nginx/blob/682f3684ea331e089aa124fe7fce8409e13c1870/src/http/modules/ngx_http_log_module.c#L957-L965

Comment: You can check this link: https://blog.logentries.com/2014/08/json-logging-in-apache-and-nginx-with-logentries/, it might help you.

Answer (score 168):

Finally it looks like we have good way to do this with vanilla nginx without any modules. Just define:

```
log_format json_combined escape=json
  '{'
    '"time_local":"$time_local",'
    '"remote_addr":"$remote_addr",'
    '"remote_user":"$remote_user",'
    '"request":"$request",'
    '"status": "$status",'
    '"body_bytes_sent":"$body_bytes_sent",'
    '"request_time":"$request_time",'
    '"http_referrer":"$http_referer",'
    '"http_user_agent":"$http_user_agent"'
  '}';
```

Note that **escape=json** was added in nginx 1.11.8.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format

Comment: I just want to add that you need to specify the log_format in your access_log definition as well, for example access_log log_path json_combined; . Also, it doesn't work with error_log, too bad.

Comment: perhaps you should also pay attention to the type of data. like `'"body_bytes_sent": $body_bytes_sent,'`  instead of `'"body_bytes_sent":"$body_bytes_sent",'`

Comment: Yup, in some cases this will be even better. Same goes for request_time.

Comment: Now if I could just get error logs to JSON I'd be all set

Comment: @BradHein: AFAIK, nginx yet to support json for error_log. Have you got it done in another way ? If so, can you share your solution ? Thanks

Comment: @Emmanuel is that safe for variables that potentially aren't set?

Comment: To answer my own question, you do not want to leave naked variables in the JSON output. If the variable is not set, it will be replaced with the empty string which will likely produce invalid JSON. An obvious solution of prefixing all numbers with zero is risky as the JSON spec officially does not allow zero prefixed numbers (probably to avoid confusion with the common representation of octal/base-8 numbers). It's probably best to wrap all variables in quotes, and then parse the numbers downstream.

Comment: Can we access to variables like `request_length` or `upstream_response_time` ?

Comment: FYI, I thought you misspelled `http_referrer` when compared to `$http_referer` but looks like this a "legacy" thing - [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer)

Comment: Is there a solution for the error log too?

Answer (score 8):

You can try to use that one https://github.com/jiaz/nginx-http-json-log - addition module for Nginx.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use:

- addition module for Nginx [nginx-http-json-log](https://github.com/jiaz/nginx-http-json-log#how-to-build)
- Use any language as done in [nginx-json-logformat](https://github.com/kmjones1979/nginx-json-logformat) with example  /etc/nginx/conf.d/[json_log.conf](https://github.com/kmjones1979/nginx-json-logformat/blob/master/etc/nginx/conf.d/json_log.conf)
- A version of the [Nginx HTTP stub status module that outputs in JSON format](https://github.com/lindsayevans/nginx-json-status-module)

PS:
[The if parameter (1.7.0) enables conditional logging](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html). A request will not be logged if the condition evaluates to “0” or an empty string:

```
map $status $http_referer{
    ~\xXX  0;
    default 1;
}

access_log /path/to/access.log combined if=$http_referer;
```

It’s a good idea to use a tool such as https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint to check your JSON data. You can test the output of your new logging format and make sure it’s real-and-proper JSON.