# Logging with Fluentd - why is the output of json log file appearing as textpayload (not jsonpayload)?

Tags: json, logging, fluentd, stackdriver, google-kubernetes-engine

I am new to Fluentd. I'm using stackdriver in GKE and I am customizing the Fluentd configuration in GKE to make some changes to the logs.

In my configuration file for the logs of my containers I have:

```
<source>
  type tail
  format json
  time_key time
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/gcp-containers.log.pos
  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%Z
  tag reform.*
  read_from_head true
</source>
```

The logs of some containers are json objests, but I see their output as textpayload (when I enable the built-in Fluentd on GKE they appear as jsonpayload).

I don't understand what could cause this.
I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this answer will cover your case, but it may save few hours of investigation to someone like it could have to me.

Although **format** parameter is now [deprecated](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/in_tail#format) and replaced with [**<parse>**](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/in_tail#<parse>-directive-(required)), 
it does support json parsing.

The crucial thing here is JSON object [structure](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry).
First nginx access log example that I've [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42564710/4246188) **do NOT work** with Stackdriver without modification:

```
log_format json_combined escape=json '{ "time_local": "$time_local", '
 '"remote_addr": "$remote_addr", '
 '"remote_user": "$remote_user", '
 '"request": "$request", '
 '"status": "$status", '
 '"body_bytes_sent": "$body_bytes_sent", '
 '"request_time": "$request_time", '
 '"http_referrer": "$http_referer", '
 '"http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent" }';
```

And this doesn't work because JSON is single level and Stackdriver requires it to be nested at least once under a single key. (At least in this example with fluentd agent, not sure for other cases)

This can be any key like *accessLog* in **WORKING example** below.

```
log_format json_combined escape=json '{ "accessLog": { "time_local": "$time_local", '
 '"remote_addr": "$remote_addr", '
 '"remote_user": "$remote_user", '
 '"request": "$request", '
 '"status": "$status", '
 '"body_bytes_sent": "$body_bytes_sent", '
 '"request_time": "$request_time", '
 '"http_referrer": "$http_referer", '
 '"http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent" } }';
```

If using *httpRequest* on the first JSON level be warned that it has [different purpose](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages).