# How to make nginx error logs in JSON instead of its default logging format?

Tags: nginx

I need to display statistics from log files on my custom GUI. The log files are expected to be huge so parsing them manually would be overkill. However, if there is a way to output the error logs in JSON instead of simple text, it could save a lot of time.

Is there a way to do that?
can we set custom log format for error_log?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049667/how-to-generate-a-json-log-from-nginx

Comment: That is for access log, I am looking for error log

Comment: Ah sorry, you can't specify your own format for error logs

Answer (score 5):

Correct, as of my knowledge, error log can not have json & custom format. however, access log can have the same.